# In react project html 5 drag and drop works on browser but not working on mobile screen

Tags: html, reactjs, redux

I created a draggable task manager app with react and redux i used html5 for drag and drop no 3rd party library. It work's perfectly on pc but not working on phones and tablets

Comment: We need code. What you said means nothing without code backing it up so we can see the problem for outselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI Touch Punch for using drag and drop functionality on mobile browser.